# proper(more effective) verb location in passive sentence

Tags: writing-style

I need put verb (developed) in proper place in that passive sentence:

First Option:
In that book **were developed** the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties.

Second Option:
In that book the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties **were developed**.

(
Proper order in English is Object - Verb (Second Option). 
But in this sentence object contains 10 words and if we put Verb - Object (First Option) then sentence more easy to read.
)

Comment: I could swear I already comment on this. (It may have just been lost during the migration.) Neither sentence is good. Far better is this: *Basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties were developed in that book.*

Comment: Better still, don't use the passive voice.